# Is it correct to say "by your thirty years old" instead of "by thirty"?

Tags: numbers

Imagine you asked someone about their plans and wishes for the future. Would it be correct to say:

> What do you hope you'll have achieved by your thirty years old?

rather than:

> What do you hope you'll have achieved by thirty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammatical reason you can't say

> What do you hope you'll have achieved by your thirty years old?

is that **your** is a possessive adjective, so like any other adjective, it modifies nouns or noun phrases.  This means it can only be followed by a noun or noun phrase, like *your hat, your religion, your best suit*.  "thirty years old" isn't a noun or noun phrase, so you can't use it there.  But you could say

> What do you hope you'll have achieved by **your thirtieth birthday**?

because "thirtieth birthday" is a noun phrase.

Comment: I prefer answers that give grammatical explanations. +1 for you!

Answer (score 4):

"By thirty" or "by age thirty" is idiomatic.  "By your thirty years old" is not.  Some possibilities:

> By (age) thirty what do you hope to achieve?
>
> By the age of thirty, what do you hope to achieve?
>
> When you reach thirty years old, what do you want to have achieved?
>
> On your thirtieth birthday, what will you have wanted to achieve?

Comment: I'll add one more: _By the time you're thirty..._